# Server Sent Event from Spring Boot application on single server with multiple UI clients

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, server-sent-events

I am new to Server Sent Event concepts. Recently I added SSEemitter in my existing Spring Boot application, taking idea from internet.

In-memory `SseEmitter` repository class is as follow:

```
@Repository
public class InMemorySseEmitterRepository implements SseEmitterRepository {

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InMemorySseEmitterRepository.class);

  private Map<String, SseEmitter> userEmitterMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  @Override
  public void addEmitter(String memberId, SseEmitter emitter) {
    userEmitterMap.put(memberId, emitter);
  }

  @Override
  public void remove(String memberId) {
    if (userEmitterMap != null && userEmitterMap.containsKey(memberId)) {
      log.info("Removing emitter for member: {}", memberId);
      userEmitterMap.remove(memberId);
    } else {
      log.info("No emitter to remove for member: {}", memberId);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public Optional<SseEmitter> get(String memberId) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(userEmitterMap.get(memberId));
  }
}
```

`SseEmitter` service class is as follows:

```
@Service
public class SseEmitterServiceImpl implements SseEmitterService {

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SseEmitterServiceImpl.class);
  private final SseEmitterRepository repository;

  public SseEmitterServiceImpl(@Value(SseEmitterRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
  }

  @Override
  public SseEmitter subscribe(String entityId, EventType eventType) {
    SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter(-1L);        //SO THAT IT NEVER TIMES OUT
    String memberId = entityId + "_" + eventType;    //MEMBER ID HAS BEEN INTRODUCED BECAUSE FOR DIFFERENT ENTITIES, FOR DIFFERENT EVENTS WE CAN SEND EVENTS FROM SERVER TO CLIENT
    emitter.onCompletion(() -> repository.remove(memberId));
    emitter.onTimeout(() -> repository.remove(memberId));
    emitter.onError(e -> {
      log.error("Create SseEmitter exception", e);
      repository.remove(memberId);
    });
    repository.addEmitter(memberId, emitter);
    return emitter;
  }
}
```

Associated resource class is as follows:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class SseEmitterResource {

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SseEmitterResource.class);
  private final SseEmitterService emitterService;

  public SseEmitterResource(SseEmitterService emitterService) {
    this.emitterService = emitterService;
  }

  @GetMapping("/subscribe/{eventType}")
  public SseEmitter subscribeToEvents(
      @PathVariable EventType eventType,
      @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "") String entityId) {
    log.info("Subscribing member with event type {} for entity id {}", eventType, entityId);
    return emitterService.subscribe(entityId, eventType);
  }
}
```

Actually, there can be multiple event type and multiple entity ids for which we should be able to send events from Server to Client.

The service class, responsible for sending the notification is as follows:

```
@Service
public class SseNotificationServiceImpl implements SseNotificationService {

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SseNotificationServiceImpl.class);

  private final SseEmitterRepository emitterRepository;
  private final DataMapper dataMapper;

  public SseNotificationServiceImpl(
      SseEmitterRepository emitterRepository,
      DataMapper dataMapper) {
    this.emitterRepository = emitterRepository;
    this.dataMapper = dataMapper;
  }

  @Override
  public void sendSseNotification(String memberId, MyDTO dto) {
    sendNotification(memberId, dto);
  }

  private void sendNotification(String memberId, MyDTO dto) {
    emitterRepository.get(memberId).ifPresentOrElse(sseEmitter -> {
      try {
        sseEmitter.send(dataMapper.map(dto));
      } catch (IOException e) {
        ...
        emitterRepository.remove(memberId);
      }
    }, () -> ...;
  }
}
```

Finally, the place, where I send this Server Sent Event notification is as follows:

```
sseNotificationService.sendSseNotification(...);
```

Now, my questions are as follows:

1. if there are multiple, say 6 clients for the Spring Boot application deployed on single POD, will all of them receive notification through the single `SseEmitter` instance, as I have shown above ?
2. If not, could anyone please help me with the changes which I need to incorporate in the above code, in order to send Server Sent Event notification to all clients ? Thanks.